# Issues with location on android

Tags: android, location

I am having trouble using locations. My code seems to fail once I try to get the lat and long from a location.

```
        String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    LocationManager locationManager; 
    Location lastKnownLocation;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Log.d(TAG, "manager made");
    lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    Log.d(TAG, "location stored");
    double lat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
    double lon = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
    Log.d(TAG, "Lat, Long got:" + lat + ", " + lon);
    distBetween(lat, lon);
    Log.d(TAG, "Distance calc complete");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListBuilder.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

It is failing when I try to call .getLatitude() and getLongitude()

And ideas why? I have internet permissions and access fine location.

Comment: check if lastKnownLocation is null or not

Comment: use the NETWORK_PROVIDER instead or switch on you gps if it returns null

Comment: Thanks, tying that now.

Comment: It appears it was null when i used GPS_PROVIDER, I have been trying to switch back and forth between an emulator and a real device. On the real device when using NETWORK_PROVIDER it returned a value. For both setting in the emulator it comes back null. I realized the GPS was off on the real device, so I will try messing with that, but for testing do you know how any tricks for the emulator. I try to send the location to gps once the app launches and it still comes back null.